# Load JSON string to HttpRequestMessage

Tags: c#, json, unit-testing, asp.net-web-api2

I'm writing some tests for my WebAPI web service and cannot figure out how to send JSON to my service method in the test.

```
ScheduleRequest sr = new ScheduleRequest();
sr.Months = null;
sr.States = null;
sr.Zip = null;
sr.Miles = null;
sr.PCodes = null;
sr.PageStart = 1;
sr.PageLimit = 10;

HttpRequestMessage m = new HttpRequestMessage();
string sr_ = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sr);

// How do I load it into the HttpRequestMessage???
// m.Content. = sr_;
var controller = new ShoppingCartController();

// Call the controlelr method and test if the return data is correct.
EventSyncResponse res = (EventSyncResponse)controller.CourseSchedule(m);
```

Am I doing this correctly, too?

**Controller Code:**

```
public object CourseSchedule(ScheduleRequest request)
{
    try
    {
        var result = cart.GetCourseSchedule(request);
        return Ok(result);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (ex.Message.StartsWith(@"ORA-20001"))
        {
            return Ok(new ParticipantResponse { FirstName = "No record found" });
        }
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: Most of the other methods can be tested via GET and don't need JSON data as parameters.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

```
[TestClass]
public class ShoppingCartControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCourseSchedule() {
        //Arrange
        var sr = new ScheduleRequest();
        sr.Months = null;
        sr.States = null;
        sr.Zip = null;
        sr.Miles = null;
        sr.PCodes = null;
        sr.PageStart = 1;
        sr.PageLimit = 10;

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(sr);
        //construct content to send
        var content = new System.Net.Http.StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage {
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/shoppingcart"),
            Content = content
        };

        var controller = new ShoppingCartController();
        //Set a fake request. If your controller creates responses you will need this
        controller.Request = request;
        //Act
        // Call the controller method and test if the return data is correct.
        var response = controller.CourseSchedule(request) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<EventSyn‌​cResponse>> ;

        //Assert
        //...other asserts
    }
}
```

But I get the impression that your Action should actually be refactored like this in your controller

```
public class ShoppingCartController : ApiController {

    public IHttpActionResult CourseSchedule(ScheduleRequest model) { ... }

}
```

which would mean that your isolated unit test should be refactored to...

```
[TestClass]
public class ShoppingCartControllerTests {
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestCourseSchedule() {
        //Arrange
        var sr = new ScheduleRequest();
        sr.Months = null;
        sr.States = null;
        sr.Zip = null;
        sr.Miles = null;
        sr.PCodes = null;
        sr.PageStart = 1;
        sr.PageLimit = 10;

       var controller = new ShoppingCartController();
        //Set a fake request. If your controller creates responses you will need this
        controller.Request = new HttpRequestMessage {
            RequestUri = new Uri("http://localhost/api/shoppingcart"),
        };
        //Act
        // Call the controller method and test if the return data is correct.
        var response = controller.CourseSchedule(sr) as OkNegotiatedContentResult<List<EventSyn‌​cResponse>> ;;

        //Assert
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

MB34.
You need to add in your method, a ScheduleRequest parameter too.
Check this link:
http://www.lybecker.com/blog/2013/06/26/accessing-http-request-from-asp-net-web-api/