# How to convert a raw Text into a raw JSON format using ASP.Net MVC?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a problem sending an `HTTP Request` to an API.

I've been receiving an `Internal Server Error 500` using the code below from my API because the content that I send is in `Text format` but it should be in `JSON format`. I've also tried `JsonConverter.SerializeObject` to convert the `fileJson` variable but it doesn't work.

```
var client = new HttpClient();
                    var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
                    {
                        Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                        RequestUri = new Uri("https://some-url"),
                        Headers = {
                            { HttpRequestHeader.Authorization.ToString(), "Bearer " + token},
                            { HttpRequestHeader.Accept.ToString(), "application/json" },
                            { HttpRequestHeader.ContentType.ToString(), "application/json"},
                            { "client-id", "clientid"},
                            { "client-secret","clientsecret"},
                            { "partner-id","partnerid"},
                            { "X-Version", "1" }
                        },
                        Content = new StringContent(fileJson)
                    };

                    var response = client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage).Result;
```

This is the string that `fileJson` contains

```
{  
   "senderRefId":"TRANSFER0001",
   "tranRequestDate":"2018-08-10T08:40:45.897",
   "particulars":"particulars",
   "sender":{  
      "name":"name",
      "address":{  
         "line1":"line1",
         "line2":"line2",
         "city":"city",
         "province":"province",
         "zipCode":"zip",
         "country":"country"
      }
   }
```

I've tested this on Postman it works when my request body is in raw `JSON format` and the error appears when its in `Text format`.

Comment: You need to set the `Content-Type` header on the `StringContent` object, not the `HttpRequestObject`.

Comment: How am i going to do that? can you give a reference for me?

Comment: @ikey: either by using the `StringContent` constructor that takes `content`, `encoding`, `mediatype` (this one) or setting it via your `stringContent.Headers.ContentType`

Comment: Have you tried [Load JSON string to HttpRequestMessage](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39021140)?